# docker-compose logs with separate yml file

Tags: docker-compose

How do I run `docker-compose logs` but using a separate yaml config?

For example, if I want to run `docker-compose up` with a separate file, I can do:

`docker-compose -f other-config.yml up`

But `-f` in `docker-compose logs` points to a service, rather than a file.

Comment: Docker will just look at the stdout of an application. Have you thought of maybe just looking at the contents of a particular file, or writing a script to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `docker-compose`, the -f options means to load a different configurations file. for `docker-compose logs`, the -f option means to follow the logs.

For your situation you need to pass the -f option twice:

`docker-compose -f other-config.yml logs -f`

You can optionally specify a service name as well at the end.

Comment: This is correct. The ordering of the -f flags are important.